# Another way to say seizures or make someone panic?

Tags: idiom-request

> The erratic behavior of AI traders gave Wall Streets a good dose of
> seizures.

This doesn't sound idiomatic. Is there a better way to say this? I am trying to find something like "made them panic", "make them have a panic attack", "gave them heart attacks", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example

> The erratic behavior of AI traders gave Wall Streets a good dose of seizures.

has several problems.

First of all the usage is "Wall Street" (singular) to refer to the US Financial district and those who work there, and by metaphor the US financial system. It is one street (and a short one at that) and the plural is simply not used.

Secondly "seizures" is not a common or good term to use when you mean panic. They are rather different. And when seizure is meant, it is not described as a "dose".

> - The erratic behavior of AI traders gave Wall Street a good dose of panic.

> - The erratic behavior of AI traders made Wall Street panic

> - The erratic behavior of AI traders sent shock waves through Wall Street.

> - The erratic behavior of AI traders made Wall Street have a panic attack.

> - The erratic behavior of AI traders left Wall Street in a panic.

Many other forms would be possible.